# Wildfly Randomly gets killed

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, wildfly

i'm with a weird problem that i tried everything and i couldn't solve it.

I have a instance of Wildfly 8.2 running a JavaEE application that controls a CallCenter, this application use like 2 ~ 8 gb memory depends on how much peopple are working, the application controls the telephony, and a web interface for configuration / reports and other sutffs.

Randomly the wildfly gets killed and i see in console the following message:

```
*** JBossAS process XXXX received kill signal ***
```

And i need to start it again.

I read about that probably being the linux OOM Killer that was killing my process, so i set in the /proc/wildfly_pid/oom_adj the value -17, as i read in documentation it makes the oom killer ignores the process, but it seems to don't work, and wildfly keeps getting killed, i did a cron job to configure the oom_adj each 1 min, and checked it, was configured correct, but nothing helps.

I was monitoring the application and the memory was like on 3 gb and its get killed, it works for some hours but randomly gets killed.

I don't know what to do, i'm using Debian 7.8 on and server that is from my client with 16gb memory and Wildfly 8.2 in standalone mode with the following java opts

```
-server -Xms256m -Xmx8192m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

A link for the dmesg output [dmesg](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17155314/dmesg.txt)

Comment: Post the output of `dmesg` (the lines since you started Wildfly).

Comment: How can i get the lines since i started wildfly? its start with the system, and at moment i can't restart it because my clients are working and restart costs alots of money to them

Comment: Most systems have timestamps on the log lines, and as root you can run `dmesg -c` to clear the buffer (and catch it the next time it happens). If you're still not sure how, you can post the whole thing, it'll just be really long.

Comment: @chrylis, my last attempt was to change overcommit_memory to 2 and overcommit_ratio to 100, as i read in documentation https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt it would let the process alloc the value of swat + 100% of physical memory if i didn't get it wrong.

Comment: That's a hack around an underlying problem and not a good approach, especially on a production system.

Comment: I know, @chrylis, but my client is losing a lot of money, and you know customer, he is losing about million per week due to it... and i can't let it falling...

Comment: @chrylis, even with this config, stills gets killed...

Comment: Your problem sounds exactly like what I had, but for me it was the OOM. Have you confirmed (e.g. grep for 'killed process' /var/log/messages) that it wasn't the OOM?

Comment: It has no logs for 'killed process' in /var/log/messages

Comment: This happens if jboss runs out of memory, i am running 8.1 on production system, and initially i had this issue, but when i configured the jvm with the following memory constraints, it never happened again.
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true" this is just for an 8gb RAM, so you could increase the maxpermsize and the Xmx considering you have 16gb RAM

Comment: I'm using java 8, perm size doesn't apply, and i'm already using 8gb for memory max i doubt will be that, but i'll increase the min memory to see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried using Java 7 instead? While tests on JDK 8, WildFly builds with Java 7 for releases.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, my code uses JDK 8 features like lambdas, i guess it's not possible to use java 7

Comment: @KennedyOliveira do you remember what was the outcome/solution to the issue?

Comment: @hakamairi hey, unfortunately, no, it's been more than 5 years haha sorry to not be of help

Comment: @kennedy for me this was a memory leak, extending memory limit helped, fixing the leak helped even more 

Answer (score 7):

*** JBossAS process XXXX received kill signal ***

This message corresponds to Java heap dump not created on OutOfMemoryError.
This can be resolved by increasing memory limits for running your task/application.

Comment: Yes, thanks for point. I checked with dmesg command.

[28984261.371802] Out of memory: Kill process 30996 (java) score 868 or sacrifice child
[28984261.372316] Killed process 30996 (java) total-vm:58787076kB, anon-rss:58016288kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[28984264.319592] oom_reaper: reaped process 30996 (java), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

this is JBossAS process